# SQL|Pandas Aggregation if a date chain does not have x days gap

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

If a date chain break is more than 30 days, it needs to be logged as a separate date chain, so the same id can have multiple date chains. For example this is my input table.

```
id  date
1   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02
1   2021-01-03
1   2021-01-10
1   2021-01-20
1   2021-03-20
1   2021-03-21
1   2021-03-22
1   2021-04-02
```

Output

```
id start_date  end_date
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-20
1  2021-03-20  2021-04-02
```

Does any knows how to do this in sql or pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to identify where new dates start.  Then a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select id, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date >= date - interval 30 day then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
            from t
           ) t
group by id, grp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` with the time difference between consecutive rows (needs sorting) to form the groups, and `agg` to get the first/last date:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
(df.groupby(df['date'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30d')).cumsum())
   ['date'].agg(start_date='first', end_date='last')
)
```

output:

```
     start_date   end_date
date                      
0    2021-01-01 2021-01-20
1    2021-03-20 2021-04-02
```

To ensure keeping the "id", you can add "id" to the `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
(df.groupby(['id', df['date'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30d')).cumsum()])
   ['date'].agg(start_date='first', end_date='last')
   .droplevel(1) # to remove the "date" group
 #  .reset_index() # uncomment to get "id" as column
)
```

output:

```
   start_date   end_date
id                      
1  2021-01-01 2021-01-20
1  2021-03-20 2021-04-02
```

Comment: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'. i am getting this error in the above query

Comment: Then you dataset is probably different than the example. Can you provide it?

Comment: lst = [[1,'2021-01-01'],[1,'2021-01-02'],[1,'2021-01-03'],[1,'2021-01-10'],[1,'2021-01-20'],[1,'2021-02-20'],[1,'2021-02-21'],[1,'2021-02-22'],[1,'2021-03-02'],[1,'2021-04-02'],[2,'2021-05-02']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['id', 'date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

Comment: maybe a version issue, i see my pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: For me this worked,
df1 = df.sort_values(by='date')
(df.groupby(['id', df['date'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30d')).cumsum()])
   ['date'].agg({'start_date': 'first', 'end_date': 'last'})
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
)

Comment: OK, glad that it worked (I am using pandas 1.2.3). No worries about the chosen answer, most important is that you got what you needed ;)